# Why can't bundler find compatible version?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying to upgrade some gems, and bundler gives me the following when doing `bundle update`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    devise_invitable was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 5.0)

    rails (= 5.1.7) was resolved to 5.1.7, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.1.7)
```

I fail to spot why it is not just using 5.1.7?

And another example:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis":
  In Gemfile:
    redis (~> 3.3.1)

    redis-objects (~> 1.2.1) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      redis (>= 3.0.2)

    sidekiq-limit_fetch was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      sidekiq (>= 4) was resolved to 5.2.8, which depends on
        redis (>= 3.3.5, < 5)

    sidekiq_newrelic_monitor was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
      redis

    split (~> 3.2.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      redis (>= 2.1)
```

Why is it not just using 3.3.x?

Bundler version 1.17.3

UPDATE from comment:

```
cat Gemfile.lock | grep 'redis'
      redis
      redis
    redis (3.3.5)
    redis-objects (1.2.1)
      redis (>= 3.0.2)
      redis (>= 3.3.5, < 5)
      redis (>= 2.1)
  redis (~> 3.3.1)
  redis-objects (~> 1.2.1)
```

Comment: Could you provide your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: @MasafumiOkura Hmm, well, it's including a lot of private repositories and gems, so it will be hard for you to reproduce from the Gemfile. Is there some other way to debug this?

Comment: Alright then, could you run the command like this? `cat Gemfile.lock | grep 'redis'`

Comment: @MasafumiOkura See update

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/6620 or try Bundler 2

Comment: Hmm, there seem no problem... What command causes the error, `bundle update` or `bundle update some_gem`?

Comment: `bundle update` I just fell over this too, seems like the same issue: https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/6620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that bundler 1.x has issues reporting the dependency issues correctly, so I upgraded to 2.x to better spot it. I did that by commenting out all but rails from my gemfiles. Then ran `bundle update` one at a time, while commenting back in more and more of the gems. As dependency issues surfaced it resolved them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the version of actionmailer yourself to the one you think will solve it, like so:
 `actionmailer, 5.1.7`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the problem while running `bundle update`, you can delete `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle update` again to regenerate `Gemfile.lock`, which might solve the problem.